# Codeigniter 4 pagination friendly uri

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, uri, codeigniter-4

I started to write a online shopping cart and i'm stuck to pagination.

For now i use default controller for homepage to show all the products paginated.

I looked to ci documentation, youtube and here for better url without page?=2 instead (pagina/2) and i try all but nothing works.

Some demo working it will be very much apreciated.

Better url segmented without parameters

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `?page=2` come for CodeIgniter4 (include in Model)
but you can manually like CodeIgniter3 : `pagina/2`